# Visual C# HEX to ASCII versus VB function

Tags: c#, .net, hex

I used this code from another post on HEX and it prefixed my Unicode value x0020 with a nul character that did not work. And it is not equivalent to the VB conversion where the leading 00 is trimmed and it gives a real value.

This is the script:

```
public static string ConvertHex(String hexString)
{
    try
    {
        string ascii = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2)
        {
            String hs = string.Empty;

            hs   = hexString.Substring(i,2);
            uint decval =   System.Convert.ToUInt32(hs, 16);
            char character = System.Convert.ToChar(decval);
            ascii += character;

        }

        return ascii;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

I changed the lines

```
char character = System.Convert.ToChar(decval);
ascii += character;
```

to this

```
ascii += (decval > 0) ? System.Convert.ToChar(decval) : "";
```

This works fine for me. My question is why is this leading nul?

And if there is a simpler solution to trim it?

Comment: You are taking two characters from your `hexString`, which is basically a byte, and then converting that byte (cast to `uint`) into a char. That is why you end up with a tw-character string from "0020".

Comment: Okay. In this case a space was encoded as uni x0020 so it was on 2 bytes, big endian encoding, I guess. So I would guess there are two approaches. What is the guideline on when to use which?